# Apache2 access.log has multiple lines that say "combine"

Tags: logging, apache2, log-files

I'm running an Apache2 webserver on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I noticed that my `access.log` has several lines that simply say `combine` on them, with no information about the request or anything else. There are other lines in the `access.log` that do *not* say `combine`, and *do* have information about the request.

Here is a sample from my `access.log`:

```
combine
combine
combine
45.129.136.74 - - [26/Aug/2021:00:17:23 -0400] "\x03" 400 0 "-" "-"
45.129.136.74 - - [26/Aug/2021:00:17:23 -0400] "\x03" 400 0 "-" "-"
combine
192.241.204.78 - - [26/Aug/2021:00:23:55 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
84.54.153.88 - - [26/Aug/2021:00:27:54 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 621 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7"
combine
combine
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:57 -0400] "POST /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:57 -0400] "POST /api/jsonws/invoke HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:57 -0400] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:57 -0400] "GET /?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php> HTTP/1.1" 200 565 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:58 -0400] "GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm HTTP/1.1" 200 565 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:58 -0400] "GET /solr/admin/info/system?wt=json HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:58 -0400] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/readme.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:58 -0400] "GET /index.php?s=/Index/\\think\\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21 HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:58 -0400] "GET /console/ HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:58 -0400] "POST /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.146.164.110 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:02:58 -0400] "GET /_ignition/execute-solution HTTP/1.1" 404 438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
45.129.136.74 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:05:21 -0400] "\x03" 400 0 "-" "-"
205.185.126.200 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:12:58 -0400] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 404 475 "http://40.121.65.70:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"
185.189.182.234 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:32:22 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
42.193.16.135 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:34:15 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 565 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; LIO-AN00 Build/HUAWEILIO-AN00; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.62 XWEB/2692 MMWEBSDK/200901 Mobile Safari/537.36"
206.189.182.136 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:45:23 -0400] "GET /ab2g HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
206.189.182.136 - - [26/Aug/2021:01:45:23 -0400] "GET /ab2h HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
combine
combine
combine
combine
combine
```

My `apache2.conf` has these lines:

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

Also in one of my `sites-enabled` configuration files I have this line:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combine
```

What do the `combine` lines mean in the access log? Why on earth would I care to see them? And how can I prevent the lines from just saying `combine` and make them actually show some useful information?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me.

Here is the line in question:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combine
```

The [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) state that the second argument is "either a nickname defined by a previous LogFormat directive, or it can be an explicit format string as described in the log formats section."

Because this is *not* a nickname defined by a previous LogFormat directive, it is treated as a format string. This means the literal word "combine" is logged.

Presumably you wanted to use the previously defined "combined" LogFormat, in which case you should just fix the typo.

Comment: Switching the line to `combined` at the end did it for me, thank you very much!

Comment: The rare "problem is a typo but on-topic"!